# how to pass a year value to a django view through a link in html

Tags: django, view, hyperlink

My django app has a couple of methods to draw a chart from given data.
I have put a  link for producing chart display page as below

```
<ul id ="dataplots" class="report">
    <li id="alldataplots_list" class="report">
        <a href="{% url alldata_report   %}"> All data Plot </a>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

Similarly ,I want to give links to create plot of  data for a particular year

I have coded the urls.py and views.py as below.What I could not figure out was,how to provide the 
link which would invoke

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/myapp/data/2011
```

sothat the view

```
'create_report_for_data_of_the_year'
```

is run.I can type this in browser bar and run it.
But I want to provide it as a link.Is a drop down list for the years the answer? Will I have to provide a form,
submit button etc and send the year as post data?

Any help/advice most welcome

thanks

mark

### urls.py

```
urlpatterns=patterns('',

url(r'^data/(?P<year>\d{4})/$','myapp.views.create_report_for_data_of_the_year',
    {
        'template_name':'myapp/report_for_data_of_the_year.html',
        'page_title':'report for data in the Year'

    },name='report_data_for_year' ),

url(r'^data/$','myapp.views.create_report_for_alldata',
    {
        'template_name':'myapp/alldata_report.html',
        'page_title':'All data report'

    },
    name='alldata_report'),

)
```

### views.py

```
def create_report_for_alldata(request,page_title,template_name):
    dataset=MyDataModel.objects.filter(creator=request.user)
    map = create_map_of_names_and_values(dataset)
    basefilename = "alldataplot"
    imgfilename = create_plot(map,basefilename)
    report_data={'basefilename':basefilename,'plot_image':imgfilename,'page_title':page_title}
    report_data["name_value_dict"]=map
    req_context=RequestContext(request,context)
    return render_to_response(template_name,req_context)

def create_report_for_data_of_the_year(request,year,page_title,template_name):
    dataset=MyDataModel.objects.filter(today__year=year,creator=request.user)
    #today is a field in MyDataModel and is a datetime.datetime 
    map = create_map_of_names_and_values(dataset)
    basefilename = "plotofdataforyear%s"%year
    page_title = page_title+" "+year
    imgfilename= create_plot(map,basefilename)
    report_data={'basefilename':basefilename,'plot_image':imgfilename,'year':year,'page_title':page_title}
    report_data["name_value_dict"]=map
    req_context=RequestContext(request,context)
    return render_to_response(template_name,req_context)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't have to use a post. This example uses an inline click handler, which you might want to refactor using jQuery or some other library, but it shows how to use a drop-down to navigate. http://lab.artlung.com/dropdown/